# template nested private class as a friend

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have the following code that doesn't compile on GCC 4.9 as well as GCC 5.1. And I can't seem to figure out why. Sorry if this is a noob question, I am kind of new to C++ templates.

```
template<class T>class A
{
    template<class X>friend class B;
    struct C {};
};

template<class X>class B 
{
    template<class T>friend struct A<T>::C;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    B<float> b;
}
```

When compiled I get the following errors

```
root@localhost# g++-49 templatefriend.cpp
templatefriend.cpp: In instantiation of âclass B<float>â:
templatefriend.cpp:38:9:   required from here
templatefriend.cpp:27:9: error: âstruct A<T>::Câ is private
  struct C {};
     ^
templatefriend.cpp:31:1: error: within this context
 {
 ^
```

where as this compiles fine if I remove the templates

```
class A
{
    friend class B;
    class C{};
};

class B
{
    friend class A::C;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, or if such a question has already been asked, please share the link.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, wrong commenting, rectified

Comment: `C` is templated since it's inside of `A`

Comment: @RyanHaining I guess I have to learn a lot about templates :p

Answer (score 2):

The warning you get from clang in this case is a bit more helpful:

```
warning: dependent nested name specifier 'A<X>::' for friend class declaration is not supported
```

In other words, A::C is a dependent type, so it doesn't work (though I don't off-hand know where in the standard this is described.

What I suspect is that in reality you only want the relationship to be between `A<T>` and `B<T>` where `T` is the same (eg `A<int>` and `B<int>` but not `A<char>` and `B<float>`).  If that is the case you can accomplish this by using the same template parameter in the friend declaration

```
template <typename T> class B;

template<class T>
class A {
    friend class B<T>;  // B of the same templated type is my friend
    struct C {};
};

template<class T>
class B {
    friend struct A<T>::C; // A::C of the same templated type is my friend
};
```

The other alternative is to have `template <typename> class A;` inside of `B`, which would then also make `A::C` a friend.

Comment: You are right about clang, just cjeck with clang++ 3.5 and got the error. But I dont want dependent friends. Means A<int>::C and B<float> can be friends too !!